# Can someone explain this z transformation to me?

Tags: transformation, integral-transforms, z-transform

I have a signal $h[n]=\frac{1}{z+3}$ and the solution is $H(z) = (-3)^{n-1}\delta[n-1]$.

Looking the solution up in a transformation table, I come to the conclusion that I need to transform $h[n]$ to look like this:

$$h[n]=\frac{z^{-1}}{z^{-1}+3}$$

But I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

Comment: That's because
$$\frac{1}{z+3} \neq \frac{1}{1+3z} = \frac{z^{-1}}{z^{-1} + 3}$$

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Do you want to tell me that my solution is not correct?

Comment: Yes.  Also, you have your $h[n]$ and $H(z)$ flipped around.